# Баг в браузерах при работе transform translate?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Коллеги, я в замешательстве. Указываю `transform: translate(x,y)` для `::after` и при ховере меняю положение элемента по вертикали с помощью `translateY(y)`. Но положение меняется и по горизонтали (сразу хочу сказать, что если меняю также с `translate(x,y)` то все нормально). Смотрю инспектор, итоговые стили почему-то преобразовались в `transform: matrix`. Сможете объяснить такое поведение? Так работает именно для псевдоэлементов, [пример тут](http://jsfiddle.net/g7euvhb8/).

```
.some {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
}
    .some:after {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: all 300ms ease;
}

.some:after {
    content: 'some';
    width: auto;
    height: 24px;
    line-height: 24px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0 10px;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 100%;
    right: 50%;
    transform-origin: 0 100%;
    transform: translate(50%, 0%);
}

.some:hover:after {
    transform: translateY(10px);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Все логично. Вы одно значение атрибута заменили другим.
У элемента не может быть двух атрибутов с одинаковым именем.

Для `:hover` вы устанавливаете смещение ТОЛЬКО по оси Y равное 10px, которое затирает указанное ранее смещение для обеих осей. Смещение по оси X принимает значение по умолчанию (это 0). А поскольку вы анимируете любые изменения, происходящие с элементом, вы наблюдаете изменение смещения по оси X с 50% до 0, а по оси Y с 0 до 10px.

Чтобы этого не происходило, указывайте значение для `:hover` в том же формате, как и для обычного состояния:

```
transform: translate(50%, 10px);
```

p.s. в первую очередь ищите ошибку в коде, а не вините браузер.

**update:**

Почитайте про [матрицу преобразований](http://htmlbook.ru/blog/matritsa-preobrazovanii).